# height and width is not changing when click on button

Tags: jquery

I have a button i want that when i click on the button the **size** of the **canvas changes by 1px**, but why my code is **not changing** the size.

```js
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  console.log("Hello");
  var fontSize = parseInt($('myCanvas').css("height"));
  var fontSize1 = parseInt($('myCanvas').css("width"));
  console.log(fontSize+ " "+ fontSize1);
  fontSize = fontSize + 1 + "px";
  fontSize1 = fontSize1 + 1 + "px";
  $('myCanvas').css({'height':fontSize});
  $('myCanvas').css({'width':fontSize1});
});
```

```css
#myCanvas{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 578px; 
  height: 200px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<button id="myButton" >Resize</button>
```

I want that when i **click** on button the size of the canvas changes from both **height and width**.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center -> Selecting Elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

Comment: you forgot `#` selector, change `$('myCanvas')` to `$('#myCanvas')`

Comment: Also, instead of getting and setting the height and width properties as strings you could just simplify `$('#myCanvas').height($('#myCanvas').height() + 1);`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // when document ready, define it!
 $("#myButton").click(function() {
  console.log("Hello");
  var fontSize = parseInt($('#myCanvas').css("height")); // use #
  var fontSize1 = parseInt($('#myCanvas').css("width")); // use #
  console.log(fontSize+ " "+ fontSize1);
    fontSize = fontSize + 1 + "px";
    fontSize1 = fontSize1 + 1 + "px";
    $('#myCanvas').css({'height':fontSize}); // use #
    $('#myCanvas').css({'width':fontSize1}); // use #
  });
})
```